# Activity not finalizing?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any reason why an activity might not be finalized (i.e. have its finalize() called) and therefore garbage collected, even though its onDestroy() is called? Is this just your average everyday memory leak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onDestroy` doesn't mean that the activity object was deleted, it just means that the activity itself (as an Android concept) was destroyed. This has nothing to do with the actual Activity object. Internally, the OS may decide to recycle it, especially when it's immediately recreated due to a configuration change (like the orientation changing from portrait to landscape).

Even IF it was garbage collected (which could happen much later after onDestroy, at a point way down the road when the system actually had to do a garbage collection because it needed memory), there's no guarantee `finalize` gets called. It's even in the documentation:

```
"Note that the VM does guarantee that finalize() is called at most
once for any object, but it doesn't guarantee when (if at all)
finalize() will be called.".
```

Generally, you should never use `finalize` unless you really have to. It's not as predictable as a destructor in C++. If you need to perform clean up in your activity, do it in `onPause` or `onDestroy` or any of the other hooks.

Comment: Then, is there any way to detect when an object is cleaned up? If finalize() isn't guaranteed to be called on cleanup, what other ways could I use to check whether something is cleaned correctly?

Comment: You may want to tell us what you're trying to do. In what case is `onDestroy`/`onStop`/`onPause` not sufficient?

Comment: Well, I do attempt to clean everything up in onDestroy, but for some reason, memory is still leaking. If finalize were guaranteed to be called, I could put a breakpoint on that and see what objects were and were not being GCed. One of my activities in particular is memory intensive, and it doesn't seem to clean up after itself correctly, which is the main cause of the issue.

Comment: You're probably using static variables, or have cross-references somewhere else (one activity is referencing a member of another one?). finalize really won't help you. If memory was low, the gc would reclaim it.

Comment: If the activity in question was the launch activity, would that prevent it from being cleaned up? I do call finish() when I move on from that activity, since it's not used afterwards, but it seems like the resources it uses is never cleaned.

Comment: No, that wouldn't matter. If the resources are not cleaned out, you might be leaking something. Do you have bitmaps? Do you keep them in static member variables? Is any data carried over to other activities? (And keep in mind that things will not necessarily be cleaned until there is actually a demand for memory.)

Comment: I do have some views in the activity that are image heavy, but they're in just regular member variables, which get nulled in onDestroy(). No data is passed over to the next activities. And my application is running into OutOfMemory exceptions because of the issue, so it should definitely be getting cleaned up.

Comment: Do you call `recycle` on the bitmaps before you let go of them? Do have ANY references to any views? And again, anything in `static` variables?

Comment: I don't load any images in code; rather that's all done from the xml layouts. Do I still need to call recycle on these bitmaps anyways? I have references to the views, but again, they get nulled. No static variables.

Comment: Are you sure that it's coming from this activity? Can you post a bit of code?